# Trying to convert input to list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to take input from user for 2 points and output the distance.
I'm getting stuck on converting the input to a list for the output.
I might be thinking about it the wrong way, any help to get me in the right direction is appreciated.

```
import math
p1 = input("please enter x1 and y1: ")
p2 = input("please enter x2 and y2: ")

x1y1 = p1.split(',')
x2y2 = p2.split(',')
distance = math.sqrt( ((x1y1[0]-x2y2[0])**2)+((x1y1[1]-x2y2[1])**2) )

print(distance)
```

Comment: `x1y1` and `x2y2` are lists of strings.  You'll have to use `int()` to convert to integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to translate the inputs into `int`s and then do a destructuring assignment to assign them to two different variables:

```
from math import sqrt

[x1, y1] = [int(n) for n in input("please enter x1 and y1: ").split()]
[x2, y2] = [int(n) for n in input("please enter x2 and y2: ").split()]

print(f"Distance: {sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert each element to int first:

```
p1 = input("please enter x1 and y1: ")
p2 = input("please enter x2 and y2: ")

x1y1 = [int(x) for x in p1.split(',')]
x2y2 = [int(y) for y in p2.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
from math import sqrt
xi, yi = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
xf, yf = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(math.sqrt((xf-xi)**2 + (yf-yi)**2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
p1 = input("please enter x1 and y1: ")
p2 = input("please enter x2 and y2: ")

x1y1 = [int(num) for num in p1.split(',')]
x2y2 = [int(num) for num in p2.split(',')]
distance = math.sqrt( ((x1y1[0]-x2y2[0])**2)+((x1y1[1]-x2y2[1])**2) )

print(distance)
```

Str should be converted to int.

Answer (score 1):

You can use map() to easily convert to int

```
import math
p1 = input("please enter x1 and y1: ")
p2 = input("please enter x2 and y2: ")

x1y1 = list(map(int, p1.split(',')))
x2y2 = list(map(int, p2.split(',')))

distance = math.sqrt( ((x1y1[0]-x2y2[0])**2)+((x1y1[1]-x2y2[1])**2) )

print(distance)
```